# Android round float

Tags: java, android, floating-point, rounding

I would like to round a float to two digits and then set it as the text of a button. I have tried multiple techniques and none of them seem to work. Can you tell me what i am doing wrong or a new way to do this.
what i have tried

```
DecimalFormat price = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
                //  price.format(cheeses);
public static String roundToOneDigit(float paramFloat) {
    return String.format("%.2f%n", paramFloat);
button3.setText("Increase price" + "$%3.2f\n"+ cheeses);
                    //float f = round(cheeses,2);
                //  float f = new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(cheeses).tofloat();
f *= 100;
                //  f = (float)Math.round(f)/100;
```

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense.  Please post the code you're using, and the result you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static String roundToOneDigit(float paramFloat) {
    return String.format("%.2f%n", paramFloat);
}

...
button3.setText("Increase price " + roundToOneDigit(cheeses) + "\n");
```

The rest is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippet has a lot of errors. For one, syntax is wrong, the method does not have closing bracket. Also, in your `button3.setText`, in your question , you said you want to round a float and then set to the button3 but in your code snippet, you did not called the method roundToOneDigit? Anyway, look below, try this into your android code.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class AndroidClass
{

    public static String roundToOneDigit(float paramFloat)
    {
        DecimalFormat price = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        return price.format(paramFloat);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        float cheese = 3;
        System.out.println("Increase price " + roundToOneDigit(cheese));
    }

}
```